# How to reorder windows in an application in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

Let's say that there are several different Windows (`CWnd`) open in a software, and the pointers to all active windows are saved in `std::vector<Node> tabsInfo`. Here is a portion of code for `Node`:

```
struct typedef Node {
...
CWnd *pWnd;
...
}
```

I have a handler to update the Z-order of all active windows using `tabsInfo`, which looks like this:

```
for (size_t i = tabsInfo.size(); i > 1; i--) {
        Node *pN_cur = &tabsInfo.at(i - 1);
        Node *pN_next = &tabsInfo.at(i - 2);
        ret = pN_cur->pWnd->SetWindowPos(pN_next->pWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE);
        ASSERT(ret != 0); // Sanity check
    }
```

However, when I debug them, even though they run without error, it makes no changes to the ordering of all windows.

Am I misunderstanding on how to use `SetWindowPos`?
When I looked other questions answered (which deals with buttons inside dialogs instead of windows), they gave the similar solution, but it doesn't seem to work here.

Comment: Are the windows you are trying to reposition child windows, owned windows, or unowned windows?

Comment: It should be `SetWindowPos(pN_next->pWnd, 0,0,0,0,...)` instead of using `NULL` (it's not an error, it's just confusing). The usage is otherwise correct, but it looks like you are doing something with tab windows or something strange so it won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who have the same problem, I added a few more lines, and it worked:

```
for (int i = tabsInfo.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        Window_Node *pWN = &tabsInfo.at(i);
        if (tabsInfo.at(i).checked) { // Ignore this line. This is program-specific
            WINDOWPLACEMENT wp = {};
            wp.length = sizeof(WINDOWPLACEMENT);
            pWN->pWnd->GetParentFrame()->GetWindowPlacement(&wp);
            wp.showCmd=SW_RESTORE;                                                                                   
            pWN->pWnd->GetParentFrame()->SetWindowPlacement(&wp);
            ret = pWN->pWnd->GetParentFrame()->SetWindowPos(NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE);
            ASSERT (ret != 0);
        } else {
        pWN->pWnd->GetParentFrame()->ShowWindow(SW_MINIMIZE);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps someone :)